# Bash script to run multiple Django application

Tags: python, django, bash

I'm new to writing bash scripts and I would like to write one to start and stop multiple Django applications.

For the stopping one, I've found a command pkill -f runserver which killed all running apps.
However, for starting multiple applications, I cant seem to get it working.
When I run one manage.py runserver command, it won't proceed onward from the first application unless I press ctrl + c.

Is there a way to run multiple django application within one bash script?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you could always add then & at the end of the command (i.e. ``` python manage.py runserver &```; and if you're fine with using ```pkill```,  then that could work.

Comment: Hi, thank you :) using and worked for me. Out of curiosity, what are the other ways to kill or stop django applications that are running? THanks

Comment: if I know there isn't going to be any other python jobs running, I just ```killall python```; but more or less I just go through the ps list and kill -9 the pids that are it.  You could always script that

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the following information will help to improve your workflow in general.
I personally use [tmux](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki) if I need to run multiple projects from one "solution". Just need some time to get into it. Here is the example of alias(that you could probably put into `.bash_profile`):

```
alias run_my_solution_dev="
tmux new -s my_solution_session -d
tmux send-keys -t my_solution_session 'cd ~/my_solution_folder' Enter
tmux split-window -v -t my_project_session:0.0
tmux send-keys -t my_solution_session:0.0 'cd my_project1_folder' Enter
tmux send-keys -t my_solution_session:0.0 'source venv/bin/activate' Enter
tmux send-keys -t my_solution_session:0.0 'python manage.py' Enter
tmux send-keys -t my_solution_session:0.1 'cd my_project2_folder' Enter
tmux send-keys -t my_solution_session:0.1 'source venv/bin/activate' Enter
tmux send-keys -t my_solution_session:0.1 'python manage.py' Enter
tmux attach -t my_solution_session
"
```

Something like that. Also, you can split another window to have ability to run commands there, like your working window.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `tmuxinator`. Maybe it can help you.

https://github.com/tmuxinator/tmuxinator